# Describe a probability distribution for $X$, such that $E[\sin(X)] = E[\cos(X)] = 2/\pi$, with certain probability bounds.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I was given an interesting problem by my mentor at university. I am currently investigating the Markov Inequality, and was recently challenged to find a random variable $X$, taking values in $[0,\pi/2]$, such that $E[\sin(X)] = E[\cos(X)] = 2/\pi$ and $Pr(X \leq \pi/3) > \frac{E(\sin(X))}{\sin(\pi/3)}$ (negation of the Markov Inequality). Does anyone have any ideas that I could possibly build off of? I've tried scaled and re-weighted uniform distributions, but have found no luck. Any help would be appreciated, Cheers!

Comment: You can try assuming it has a density. That gives you two integral equalities and one integral inequality.

Comment: The problem is still massively underdetermined. Perhaps it might help to restrict yourself to indicator/step functions?

Comment: @whpowell96 this is the direction I am trying to go in now. Currently trying to define a distribution for only 2 points in the support, and then progressing from there. Let me know if you have a crack at it.